# OpsHub-014371 Error (404)Not Found on User Mapping Page

Tags: opshub

I am trying to migrate source code from TFS 2010 SP1 (local on prem) to TFS Online. When I get to the User Mapping page, I get this error:

> com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not
>   instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source
>   1443539882111 ALM TFS 1443539882115, due to (404)Not Found

I am running this on the TFS App Tier itself with the database being local.
I have stopped the McAfee services.
I ran the utility as Admin.
I have only 2 users in the project and they are in both projects (I am the TFS Admin locally).
I have performed the steps in the Walkthrough, except for the process template. We shouldn't need that because we're migrating source code only.
I have cleared the cache folders.

The error entry in the log file:

> 09/29/2015 11:18:02,344 ERROR [http-8989-1]
>   (com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - OpsHub-014371:
>   Could not instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS
>   Source 1443539882111 ALM TFS 1443539882115, due to (404)Not Found
>   com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not
>   instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source
>   1443539882111 ALM TFS 1443539882115, due to (404)Not Found    at
>   com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl.getProjectsMeta(TFSMetadataImpl.java:63)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a4e716d.CGLIB$getProjectsMeta$0()
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a4e716d$$FastClassByCGLIB$$465c721.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.caching.MetadataCacheHandler.intercept(MetadataCacheHandler.java:40)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.metadata.impl.TFSMetadataImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5a4e716d.getProjectsMeta()
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.business.ConfigServiceBusiness.getUserList(ConfigServiceBusiness.java:926)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl.getUserList(ConfigServiceImpl.java:407)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f3d793b0.CGLIB$getUserList$6()
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f3d793b0$$FastClassByCGLIB$$148b3d41.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.service.ServiceInterception.intercept(ServiceInterception.java:44)
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f3d793b0.getUserList()
>     at
>   com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigService.getUserList(ConfigService.java:97)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
>     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

From OVSMU.log file:

> 2015-09-29 11:18:02,351 [1] ERROR
>   com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not
>   instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source
>   1443539882111 ALM TFS 1443539882115, due to (404)Not Found
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   com.opshub.eai.metadata.MetadataException: OpsHub-014371: Could not
>   instantiate metadata implementation for For User List | TFS Source
>   1443539882111 ALM TFS 1443539882115, due to (404)Not Found

Server stack trace:

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:

> at
>   TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.UserMappingViewModel.worker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object
>   sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in
>   e:\OVSMUBranch\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\UserMappingViewModel.cs:line
>   416    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)

Is it possible that this has something to do with the Java runtime? Perhaps I need to install a newer JRE?

Comment: The migration utility has a help link to http://www.opshub.com/ohrel/Resources/TFS/permissions.php, which states: Be sure to tag your questions with #OpsHub and #visual-studio-online so that our team can find and address them easily. Whether or not my question has anything to do with VSO, the instructions are clear that it is to be included.

Comment: Hi Mike, is the machine where the utility is running behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes it is. We got instructions from Microsoft for adding the following environment variable:                                                                                      Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable Value: -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.pa.gov -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=cwopa\userid -Dhttp.proxyPassword=yourpwd -Dhttps=false